# Excel Conditional formatting both the cell and one cell to the right

Tags: excel, cell-formatting

I have a calendar in Excel I am doing some Conditional formatting on, I am supposed to insert letters and each letter must then format both the cell and the cell on the right in a color. It is no problem to format the cell the letter is in, it can be done in several ways as example =I10="P" But how do I get the cell on the right to follow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create your rule you must put dollar signs (ex : $H$13) on the letter and number of column and row, that way the conditional formatting will only check the initial cell and the other cell on the right won't have to respect the condition. However don't forget to apply your formatting on the right cell otherwise it won't work.

You'll find a link with an image of an example. My excel is in french but you should understand quickly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/03cZW.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much, just so I understand it correctly, Then I have to make a formatting rule for all colors, for each month.
I have 6 colors and 13 months, so 78 rules, otherwise the colors will color into each other's months, hope that make sence :-)

Comment: That's a lot of rules. I can't try it for you now but start to record a macro manually and format a column. After that take the code and only the instruction that seems to be useful to format. Then add a loop with something like " for each month " and 6 variables depending on the letter. specfiy that you want the format to be applied only the style "$H13". If I have time I'l try on my side and good luck (if you succeed I'm interested in the code).